# how can I set a dummy variable in a regression in R

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

The following is my data

```
y   r1  r2  r3

1   0.1 0.2 -0.3
2   0.7 -0.9    0.03
3   -0.93   -0.32   -0.22
```

1.The first question is how can I get the output like this:

```
y   r1     r2    r3    dummy_r1  dummy_r2 dummy_r3

1   0.1    0.2   -0.3    0        0          1
2   0.7   -0.9   0.03    0        1          0
3   -0.93 -0.32  -0.22   1        1          1
```

Note:I want the negative data equals to 1, and the positive data equals to 0

2.The second question is that if I want to do the regression like: `lm(y~r1+r2+r3+dummy_r1+ dummy_r2+dummy_r3)`,what should I do if I don’t want to use the output `data(dummy_r1,dummy_r2,dummy_r3)` above, because it is not convenient.

Comment: 1) `sapply(data[2:4], function(x) as.integer(x < 0))`. 2) After `cbind(data, output_of_previous)` just do `lm(y ~ ., data)`.

Comment: You may not really need to generate dummy variables:  `lm(y~r1+r2+r3+(r1<0) +(r2<0)+(r3<0)...)` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end, define `DF2` to also have the `sign.*` columns and then run the regression on that. Of cousse you don't have enough data shown in the question to actually get coefficients for so many predictors but if in your real problem you have more data then it should be ok.

```
DF2 <- cbind(DF, sign = +(DF[-1] < 0))
lm(y ~., DF2)
```

giving:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = DF2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           r1           r2           r3      sign.r1  
      1.425       -1.163       -1.543           NA           NA  
    sign.r2      sign.r3  
         NA           NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "y   r1  r2  r3
1   0.1 0.2 -0.3
2   0.7 -0.9    0.03
3   -0.93   -0.32   -0.22"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```